# BBsolve solutions

Tags: r, math

Good morning,

After using BBsolve to solve a nonlinear system, i would like to know if there is a way to extract the solutions one by one, for some reason i could not do that, i tried doing this :

```
> library(BB)
> v<-BBsolve(par =c(19.9,0.15,0), fn = g)
Successful convergence.
> s<-v[1]
> s
$par
[1]  1.425961e+01 -9.259611e+00  5.223318e-21

> s[1]
$par
[1]  1.425961e+01 -9.259611e+00  5.223318e-21
```

As you can see it did not work!!!!

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try `s$par[1]`.

Comment: thank you, the solution was putting $par after; like this    v<-BBsolve(par =c(19.9,0.15,0), fn = g)$par,     it works and gives you the solution as a vector so extracting works perfectly.